# Image shifts when removing percent (%) signs with standalone class

Tags: spacing, standalone, comments

I have occasionally observed that some LaTeX macros behave differently with and without end-of-line comments. My understanding of this is that a macro may leave a space on the stack that for some reason is removed **if** the macro is ended with a percent sign. I have never quite understood why this happens so I've slowly fallen into the habit of ending **all** "function calls" in LaTeX with %. In the present case, I discovered that `\pstScalePoints` and `\newpsstyle` behaves just like that and took the effort to isolate the problem into the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\listfiles
\begin{document}
\readdata{\mytable}{table.txt}  
\pstScalePoints(1.0,1.0){1.0 div}{1.0 div}%  <-- NB!
\newpsstyle{legendstyle}{fillstyle=solid}%   <-- NB!
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(0,0)(1,1){1cm}{1cm}
\listplot{\mytable}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

Problem: The output changes if the two end-of-line % signs are removed. My suspicion is that the macros leave behind a space on the stack, but I do not know how to correct it - other than stubbornly adding % to **all** the macro endings!

The contents of file `table.txt` is:

```
0.0, 0.00
0.2, 0.04
0.4, 0.16
0.6, 0.36
0.8, 0.64
1.0, 1.00
```

I halfway expect that the problem depends on which packages I am using so I therefore include the output from `\listfiles`:

```
pstricks.sty      2013/12/12 v0.60
pstricks.tex      2014/10/25 v2.60
pst-xkey.tex      2005/11/25 v1.6
pst-fp.tex        2014/10/25 v2.60
pstricks-add.sty  2010/02/11 v.0.14
pst-plot.sty      2011/04/13
pst-xkey.sty      2005/11/25 v1.6
pst-plot.tex      2014/08/23 1.70
pst-node.sty      2010/04/22
pst-node.tex      2014/08/04 1.35
pstricks-add.tex  2014/12/08 v3.77
pstricks-add.cfg  2005/01/10 v0.1
```

Finally, I've attached two pictures illustrating the problem:

1. With end-of-line comment
   [image: With end-of-line comment]
   <sub>(source: [ntnu.no](http://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/haugwarb/plot_with_comment.png))</sub>
2. Without end-of-line comment
   [image: Without end-of-line comment]
   <sub>(source: [ntnu.no](http://www.nt.ntnu.no/users/haugwarb/plot_without_comment.png))</sub>

Comment: The shift that you observe are the two spaces corresponding to the two line ends. You should rather ask why sometimes/often the space at the line end does *not* become visible. There are two major reasons why the space is ignored: If the line ends with a macro name like `\abc`, then the space is consumed as part of the parsing rules of TeX. The other situation is that the command explicitly consumes the space, like `\begin` or `\end` statements do, and apparently also `\readdata` does. You can achieve the same effect for your own macro definitions by ending them with `\ignorespaces`.

Comment: By default, `standalone` typesets its contents in a horizontal box, so spaces are significant. You need also a `%` after `\readdata{\mytable}{table.txt}`. In a normal document those spaces would be ignored since LaTeX has not yet started a paragraph.

Comment: your first line implies that the `%` behaviour is related to macros which is not the case. compare `a<newline>b` which typesets as `a b` but if you comment out the newline then naturally it comments out the space so you get `ab`

Comment: Thanks @egreg, for enlightening me about `standalone`. I did not come to my mind that it works in horisontal mode! On the other hand, I cannot see any difference if `\readdata` is ended with `%`or not. Is there something I have (still) misunderstood?

Comment: @ToreH-W Actually, `\readdata` calls an inner macro whose replacement text ends with `\ignorespaces`, so indeed it does not matter whether you have `%` after that line. Just checked. I was bitten by the issue a couple of times, so I learnt about it.

Comment: Since we're talking about spaces: Where can I find a little more information on this topic? I know the basics - that macros consumes space and that newline acts like a space in horizontal mode -;) - but when @gernot mentions that `\begin`and `\end` explicitly consume the space, I know I should read up a bit.

Answer (score 12):

This is a specific problem of `standalone`. You can look at [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines) for understanding what follows.

By default, `standalone` typesets the text in the `document` environment in a horizontal box (`\mbox`, essentially), for later cropping.

In a horizontal box, spaces are significant, so the end-of-lines must be hidden with `%` lest they're converted into spaces.

In a normal document, say with `\documentclass` article`, you wouldn't see those spaces, because they are seen when TeX has not yet started a paragraph.

So

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\readdata{\mytable}{table.txt}%  <-- NB!
\pstScalePoints(1.0,1.0){1.0 div}{1.0 div}%  <-- NB!
\newpsstyle{legendstyle}{fillstyle=solid}%   <-- NB!
\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(0,0)(1,1){1cm}{1cm}
\listplot{\mytable}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\readdata{\mytable}{table.txt}  
\pstScalePoints(1.0,1.0){1.0 div}{1.0 div}
\newpsstyle{legendstyle}{fillstyle=solid}

\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(0,0)(1,1){1cm}{1cm}
\listplot{\mytable}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

needs no `%` because the paragraph starts with `\begin{psgraph}`.

If you find yourself doing many of this `%` additions, you can consider adding something to your document:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\newcommand{\startsetup}{%
  \chardef\oldendlinechar\endlinechar
  \endlinechar=-1
}
\newcommand{\stopsetup}{\endlinechar=\oldendlinechar}

\begin{document}

\startsetup
\readdata{\mytable}{table.txt}
\pstScalePoints(1.0,1.0){1.0 div}{1.0 div}
\newpsstyle{legendstyle}{fillstyle=solid}
\stopsetup

\begin{psgraph}(0,0)(0,0)(1,1){1cm}{1cm}
\listplot{\mytable}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```